# What is the Best Practice for malloc?

Tags: c, char, malloc

Which if any of the following are correct and would be considered best practice to create a char string capable of holding 100 characters?

```
char * charStringA = malloc(100);
char * charStringB = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
char * charStringC = (char*)malloc(100);
char * charStringD = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
```

Comment: heck here http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/to-cast-or-not-to-cast-malloc-return.html

Comment: They are all "correct" syntax. Your problem is not on a syntax level, so please change the header of your question accordingly. I'd go for "best practice" instead of "correct syntax".

Comment: Well ... if you want a string with 100 "visible" characters you need to allocate 101 bytes. The "extra" byte can then hold the terminating '\0'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
char * charStringA = malloc(100);
char * charStringB = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
```

Both are equally correct.
Two important points that should be considered in this evaluation are:

1. size of `char` is guaranteed to be one byte by the C standard.
2. A `void` pointer can be assigned to any pointer without an explicit cast in C and the casting is unnecessary. Casting the return value of `malloc` is considered as an bad practice because of the following:

**[What's wrong with casting malloc's return value?](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html)**

---

The above answer applies to the options mentioned in the OP. An better practice is to use `sizeof` without making any assumptions about the size of any *type*. This is the reason and purpose that `sizeof` exists. In this case the best practice will be to use:

```
char * charStringB = malloc(sizeof(*charStringB)*100);
```

Note that `*charStringB` is same as `char` but this gives you the flexibility that if you want to change the *type* in future then there is fewer number of places where you need to remember to make modifications.

Comment: But as a best practice I would go for `malloc(sizeof(char)*100)`, since for any other type you need `sizeof`.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs: That is precisely correct. The answer only evaluates the options mentioned in the OP. As a general good practice, one should **never** assume size of any *type*, this is the reason `sizeof` was provided.

Comment: the benefit of `char * charStringB = malloc(sizeof(*charStringB)*100);` is that if we decide to support Unicode (16 or 32-bit characters), all that needs to change [on this line] is the `char` changed to `wchar_t`, and everything else will work as expected.

Answer (score 5):

The most general form is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { int a; char b[55]; } Thing;

Thing *p;
p = malloc (100 * sizeof *p);
```

This works indepentely of the actual definition of `Thing`, so if you would "reuse" the line as

```
Typedef { float water; int fire; } OtherThing;
OtherThing *p;
p = malloc (100 * sizeof *p);
```

it would still function as intended.

The original case would yield:

```
char *p;
p = malloc (100 * sizeof *p);
```

, where the `sizeof *p` would of course be superfluous (since `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition) , but it won't hurt.

BTW: this answer is mostly about style. Syntactically, all variants are acceptible, given you include stdlib.h (or manually introduce a prototype for malloc())

Answer (score 3):

The first one, since char is always one byte, cast of malloc is only necesary in c++

Comment: And why would some one use malloc in C++?

Comment: Touche ;) ... but maybe for compile in C style using external C