# C language: pointer returned by malloc() and casting

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
>   [What is the Best Practice for malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099967/what-is-the-best-practice-for-malloc)

Im new with c language and i have a question
as i was explained in class:

> The type of the pointer returned by malloc() is void *, and therefore
>   we need to cast it into the required type

which means i need to do:

```
char *str;
str = (char *) malloc(14);
```

but i dont understand, is it a must? lets say malloc returns that void pointer, why do i see many of examples around **without** doing the casting? an example:

```
float *arr = malloc (20 * sizeof (float));
```

Could anyone please explain :) ?

Comment: A void pointer can be converted to and from any (non-function) pointer **without a cast**. You don't need the cast. Remove it, since it is just cargo cult/ candy.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html

Comment: Basically, you don't cast it because it's dangerous.

Comment: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, this cast is not required. The conversion is indeed implicit.

> **C11 (n1570), § 6.3.2.3 Pointers**
>
> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to
>   any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall
>   compare equal to the original pointer.

Since it is unecessary, cast `malloc` return or not is another question (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)).

Comment: thanks a lot! used ur explaination and the above ones